# It is possible to data from topics in xslx file?

Tags: ros, rospy, data

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had read subscriber to recieve data and now curious about save that data instead of real time in xslx format (not using bag files). Are there any ways to do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270312/it-is-possible-to-data-from-topics-in-xslx-file-?/) by [Sol](https://answers.ros.org/users/31466/sol/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-09-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-09-06**:
Would a CSV file of some kind be okay? One that could be imported into Excel? If so generating CSV files directly in code is easy in C++ and Python (in Python you could use built-in CSV writers like `numpy.savetxt` or the [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)).

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-09-06**:
There are also some tools for converting bag files to CSV (e.g. [rosbag_to_csv](https://github.com/AtsushiSakai/rosbag_to_csv)) or `rostopic echo -p -b <bagname> /topicname > <csvfilename>`. If you need XLSX, you could look into something like [xlswriter Python](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io)

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-06**:
I've used xlsxwriter to write xlsx files from a bag file and it's very easy to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the comments on your question by @jarvisschultz and myself, yes it is possible. You can use any library that writes `xlsx` files such as what @jarvisschultz suggested ([XlsxWriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/)).

I've used XlsxWriter myself and it's quite easy. Just follow the [tutorials from the documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/contents.html).

You can also use the [Working with Excel Sheets Chapter](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/) from the book, Automate the Boring Stuff with Python, which uses `openpyxl`.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1